# Как скопировать сайт. wget не работает

Tags: javascript, html5, wget

Подскажите как скопировать сайт. wget не работает. --no-check-certificate тоже пробовал. Может есть программа, которая сможет скачать все файлы?

вот ссылка http://growseedshop.com

Структура папки с сайтом. Копируется только половина. Без папки fiels, thumbs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откуда надо копировать? Копи паста не катит? Или сайт не ваш?

Comment: Нужно скопировать по доменному имени. Копи паста катит. Нужно точь в точь скопировать

Comment: Что то тогда проблема не ясна...копируете весь сайт, подставляете конфиги.

Answer (score 0):

Ну это распространенная проблема. Программы, конечно, можно использовать, но они не решают всех задач. Да, не всегда все качается с помощью Wget.

Попробуйте такие [онлайн-сервисы для копирования сайтов](https://sitecopy.pro/), как http://sitecopy.pro/ или подобные. Там вам и сайт скопируют и отредактируют его содержимое, настроят формы для сообщений и заявок, если нужно прикрутят админку.

Главное, перед тем как заказать копию, уточните все моменты, составьте техническое задание и попросите сделать тестовую копию, чтобы убедиться, что ваш сайт копируется.